# how to focus on a particular box on modal popup in jquery

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog, focus

I am using a modal popup in which I am using a following code using jquery custombox. I want to focus on a particular box as soon as the popup opens.

I am using jquery custom box v.1.1.3

```
$('.fadein').on('click', function ( e ){

        $.fn.custombox(this), {    effect: 'fadein'
        });
        e.preventDefault();   $('.auto').autoNumeric('init');
    });
```

I am wondering if someone could help resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `open callback` and remove `)` immediate after `this` like,

```
$('.fadein').on('click', function ( e ){
    $.fn.custombox(this, { // remove the extra closing bracket after this. 
       effect: 'fadein',
       open: function () {
           $('.auto').autoNumeric('init'); // I think this you want after opening box
           // or your code to focus element
       }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```